# How can I record the time data are entered to Excel cells without VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, powerbi, powerquery

I want to recorded the time when data are entered in our production datasheets.

```
Product Datasheet 1.xlsx

Time               Amount
2021-07-12 06:00   2
2021-07-13 12:00   3
...
    
Product Datasheet 2.xlsx
    
Time               Amount
2021-07-05 16:00   2
2021-07-09 22:00   6
...
    
Product Datasheet 3.xlsx
...
```

The datasheets are saved on network and can shared by many people so I cannot change them to xlsm files or run macros in them. I tried to retrieve from each of the sheets with power query and preserve different versions every hour in a separate file created by myself. Data entry time can be obtained by comparing their differences. But I have to refresh them manually every hour. Are there any better ways to do it? Can Power BI monitor the data? Can Access do it?

Comment: "The datasheets are saved on network and can shared by many people" - not sure why that makes VBA not an option.

Comment: There's probably a more elegant function to use, but something hinky like: `=IF(A1<>"whatever", NOW(), "")` will update every time cell `A1` is changed in anyway.

Comment: Excel used as GUI for data entry to Access database? Why not use Access as frontend?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for replying! I've seen people record the time with a sub. But in that case, the file has to be saved as another xlsm file. The links in the original xlsx file would not be valid anymore. Is there any way to record the time without saving to another file?

Comment: @June7 Thanks for replying. It's a historical problem. The business was small and nobody is interested in computer other than me. So people keep using Excel.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for replying! Tried that formula before. But the time would refresh when new data are entered.